# Not seeing urls using HTMLAgility (nor view source in Chrome) for a particular website

Tags: html, url, document, scrape

I've had very good luck doing some HTML scraping from the state gov't job board as well as several other job listing websites, using HTMLAgilityPack and the sample code.  However when I try to scrape **dice** for job listing urls, I/HAP don't see any of them.   When I do view source in the actual webpage (in Chrome) I don't see the search results that I see on screen and tried collapsing a few dozen >'s and didn't see any, so it's more of an HTML misunderstanding than a HTMLAgility issue.   I just pasted a url for searching dice (the career website with job listings) here, not sure if SO will remove.  But I guess the urls are hidden someone, which seems odd, but maybe it's anti-scrape?   Thanks in advance for any direction!

// "https://www.dice.com/jobs?q=test&location=Plano,%20TX%2075093,%20USA&latitude=33.0386278&longitude=-96.8243812&countryCode=US&locationPrecision=PostalCode&radius=30&radiusUnit=mi&page=1&pageSize=20&language=en";

Comment: Looks like the site is rendered by Angualr, There is no HTML per-se to scrape as it not there on inital page load, but rendered later by javascript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

F12 is your friend in any browser. Look at the network tab. The data you are interested in is of type "xhr" and its name is "seeker". No need to use HTMLAgilityPack.
All you need to do is parse the Json returned by your url.

1. Write code to download the json string from the URL. The following code works for me :

   ```
               using System.Net;

               using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
               wc.Headers.Add("authority", "job-search-api.svc.dhigroupinc.com");
               wc.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
               wc.Headers.Add("origin", "https://www.dice.com");
               wc.Headers.Add("referer", "https://www.dice.com/");
               wc.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
               wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
               wc.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "1YAt0R9wBg4WfsF9VB2778F5CHLAPMVW3WAZcKd8");

               string downloadedJson=   wc.DownloadString("https://job-search-api.svc.dhigroupinc.com/v1/dice/jobs/search?q=test&locationPrecision=PostalCode&latitude=33.0386278&longitude=-96.8243812&countryCode2=US&radius=30&radiusUnit=mi&page=1&pageSize=20&facets=employmentType%7CpostedDate%7CworkFromHomeAvailability%7CemployerType%7CeasyApply%7CisRemote&fields=id%7CjobId%7Csummary%7Ctitle%7CpostedDate%7CmodifiedDate%7CjobLocation.displayName%7CdetailsPageUrl%7Csalary%7CclientBrandId%7CcompanyPageUrl%7CcompanyLogoUrl%7CpositionId%7CcompanyName%7CemploymentType%7CisHighlighted%7Cscore%7CeasyApply%7CemployerType%7CworkFromHomeAvailability%7CisRemote&culture=en&recommendations=true&interactionId=0&fj=true&includeRemote=true&eid=a6zd7NUgR0Wy8Tzf36TS2Q_");
           }
   ```
2. Copy the whole result on your clipboard.
3. In Visual Studio create a new class file
4. Click Edit > Paste special > Paste Json as classes.
   In your code you will need the name of the first class that you pasted. It is the parent class called Rootobject by default
5. Install Newtonsoft.Json

> ```
>  using Newtonsoft.Json
>  Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Rootobject>(downloadedJson);
> ```

Now you can loop through the Data array to extract all of the job info you need.

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.data.Length; i++)
                {
                    string companyName = obj.data[i].companyName;
                    string salary = obj.data[i].salary;
                }
```

Comment: I appreciate what you put, but have not had time to walk thru, but hope tonight or tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieChaplin Ok let me know Charlie