# How should I use HtmlAgilityPack to scrape a table on a website?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to scrape a table from a website with C# and export the data into pgadmin as a database that would store the data for usage later on. I´ve tried to use different methods that I have seen on the internet and the "await" method seems to be the best way according to others. I have not found any example of its usage and therefore the following code is what I have come up with. (I use windows forms in visual studio)

```
string url = ("internet website here");

                        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
                        string page = webclient.DownloadString(url);

                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadHtml(page);

                        List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"cr_cashflow\"]/div[2]/div/table")
                            .Descendants("tr")
                            .Where(tr=>tr.Elements("td").Count() > 0)
                            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                            .ToList();dataGridTable1.Datasource=table
```

The internet xpath is the following that I want to scrape:

```
<table class='cr_dataTable>
 <tbody>
   <tr classs>
       <td class>Values</td>
       <td class>1,356</td>
       <td class>1,256</td>
       <td class>1,459</td>
       <td class>1,535</td>
```

What I have is to copy the xpath of the table "cr_dataTable".

Now to the problem, as I'm new to the programming world I'm still learning how this method works and the code tells me:

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectNodes(...) returned null."

How should I think about the usage of this method to find the values of "cr_dataTable" without getting the return null message? At this point I dont know what i´m missing for the code to work. Thankful if someone knows thats wrong in the code and how to make it work.

Comment: See this example from the HtmlAgilityPack docs: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-web it shows how to do what you want I believe. No need to use `WebClient`

Comment: If the website is consuming json, consider this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/73447212/4180382

Comment: Can you include the webite you're trying to scrape ?

Comment: @OleEHDufour Yes, for example a website like: [link](wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA/financials/annual/balance-sheet) where the table can change in size and number of rows

Answer (score 0):

According to your reply, I wrote new code. You can refer to this.

What I want to emphasize is that table."SelectNodes(".//tr")" can parse all the "tr" information under this table. And "table.SelectNodes("//tr")" gets all the "tr" of the current html, if there are two tables, it will get all the "tr" information of the two tables. Which one to use depends on the situation.

Code show as below:

```
        var url = @”html://111.com”;
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.Load(url);

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml("//*[@id=\"cr_cashflow\"]/div[2]/div/table");
        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("row");
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("cell:" + cell.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Is it possible to make the doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes dynamic? What I mean is that the table on the website will sometimes show less values or more and if I manually select nodes it will get the message that teh select node cant be found or is null